# Logical Consequence and Tarski's World

Tags: logic

I found this question in an old exam paper. I have no idea what is expected from a question like this.

Consider the Tarski's world below. This world illustrates that `¬∃xTet(x)` is NOT a logical consequence of the premises below. Explain why/

```
1. ∀x∀y [LeftOf(x, y] → Larger(x, y)]
2. ∀x∀y [Smaller(y, x) → (Cube(x) ∧ Dodec(y))]
```

[image]

This is worth 6 marks.

I think the obvious things are that you cannot infer `¬∃xTet(x)` from the premisses.

Maybe I just don't really understand the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to show that the conclusion is **not** a *logical consequence* of the premises, we have to find a counter-example, i.e. a "world" were the premsies are ture and the conclusion is not.

After having checked that the two premises are satisfied in the "world" depicted, we can conlude that ¬∃xTet(x) it is **not** true, simply because there are two tetrahedra.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but do you think that is worth 6 marks?

Comment: @Leon - I do not know what are "marks"; you have to ask to your instructor ...

Comment: I'm referring to the number of points rewarded for a correct answer in the exam.

Comment: @Leon - it seems to me that the gist of the question is "Explain why". Thus, we have to supplement the answer : "that we cannot infer the conclusion from the premisses" with an argument showing that in the world depicted the two premises are satisfied... I think. :)